# Basic questions about Verdier duality

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety with a stratification $X_{\alpha}$ (all the strata are even dimensional) with $d = \dim X$. We write $i_{\alpha} : X_{\alpha} \to X$ for the inclusion.

We fix a perversity, i.e a function $p : \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$ with $p(0) = 0$ and $p(n) - p(n-1) \in \{0,-1\}$ for all $n \geq 0$.

We define the perverse $t$-structure by $$^pD^{\leq 0} = \{A \mid  \text{for all $\alpha$, }\mathscr H^k(i_{\alpha}^*A) = 0, \forall k > p(\alpha) \} $$  $$^pD^{\geq 0} = \{A \mid \text{for all $\alpha$, } \mathscr H^k(i^!_{\alpha}A) = 0, \forall k < p(\alpha)\}$$

> Question : How to see that $\Bbb D (^pD^{\leq 0}) \subset \ ^qD^{\geq 0}$ ?

Here $q$ is the complementary perversity, defined by $q(n) = -n-p(n)$ and $\Bbb D$ is the Verdier duality functor.

**What I tried** :

So let $A \in \  ^pD^{\leq 0}$. We have $\mathscr H^i(i_{\alpha}^!(\Bbb D A)) = \mathscr H^i(\Bbb D i^*_{\alpha} A) = \mathscr H^i(\mathscr{RHom}(i^*_{\alpha}A,\omega_X))$

Now I assume that $\omega_X \cong \Bbb C_X[d]$. We get $$\mathscr H^i(\mathscr{RHom}(i^*_{\alpha}A,\omega_X)) = \mathscr H^{i+d}(\mathscr{RHom}(i^*_{\alpha}A, \Bbb C_X)) \cong \mathscr H^{-i-d}(i^*_{\alpha}A)$$ The claim follows in this case but I don't know how to deal with the general case.

Comment: You are almost there : note that it should be $R\mathscr{H}om(i_\alpha^*A,\omega_{X_\alpha})$ and not $\omega_X$. Now, use the fact that $X_\alpha$ is smooth so $\omega_{X_\alpha}=\mathbb{C}_{X_\alpha}[d_\alpha]$.

Comment: @Roland : thanks a lot ! I deduce $ \Bbb D \ ^p D^{\leq 0} \subset \ ^q D^{\geq c_{\alpha}}$ (where $c_{\alpha} = \text{codim}(X_{\alpha})$) which is stronger. Thank you again.

Comment: No there is a mistake in your proof, you should not have that. Note that $q(\alpha)=-d_\alpha-p(\alpha)$...

Comment: @Roland This is embarassing. Maybe I should review high school math before trying to understand perverse sheaves. Once more thank you for helping me :-)